# Move an element to another parent after changing its ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML like this:

```
<span class="file-wrapper" id="fileSpan">
    <input type="file" name="photo[]" id="photo" />
    <span class="button">Click to choose photo</span>
</span>
```

I want to extract the input field from there, change its ID and put it in an other div.

How can I do that? If jQuery is needed that's okay, but if it can be without that would be great.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It's certainly easy in jQuery:

```
// jQuery 1.6+
$("#photo").prop("id", "newId").appendTo("#someOtherDiv");

// jQuery (all versions)
$("#photo").attr("id", "newId").appendTo("#someOtherDiv");
```

> **Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/a93Az/**

---

If you want to do it in plain ol' JS, it's still fairly simple:

```
var photo = document.getElementById("photo");
photo.id  = "newId";
document.getElementById("someOtherDiv").appendChild(photo);
```

> **Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/a93Az/1/**

Comment: @Royi: easily ported to older versions, just change `prop()` to `attr()`.

Comment: Shouldn't we opt for the newest version of jQuery when possible anyways?

Comment: @Bracketworks: I would say so.  IIRC, `prop()` should be a little more efficient than `attr()` because there's less work to do compatibility-wise.

Comment: It's worth explaining  that when you use `appendChild` (or `append` or `appendTo`) with an existing DOM element, that element is moved to the new location, not copied there.

Comment: @mblase75: maybe, but isn't that fairly explanatory when reading or testing the code?  In any case, the working demos should clear up any confusion :-)

Comment: @AndyE: it's not necessarily obvious from the dictionary definition of "append." That's why it's worth explaining to someone new to the technique.

Comment: @mblase75: my point was that the use of "append" in the answer and no mention of the word "move" implies that `appendTo` works in that way.