# Change structure of HTML document on mobile view

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Is it possible to adjust the HTML structure while moving from Desktop view to Mobile view? For example,

```
<div class="container1">
    <div class="dropdown1">Some HTML here</div>
</div>
<div class="container2">
    <div class="dropdown2">Some HTML here</div>
</div>
```

I want to render both the dropdowns inside "container1" when using Mobile view. Is it possible?

Comment: It is possible only trough javascript. But I don't think this is what you really want to achieve. Try thinking of something else, and try using CSS media queries for that. They are way faster and less consuming than javascript.

Comment: The code I am trying to work on is part of an existing project so cannot change the structure. The change is only required in Mobile view. Consider the above code for desktop view. That should remain unchanged.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve, visually speaking?

Comment: You would need to provide a lot more details, including the parent element, the relevant parts of the existing CSS, how it looks on the desktop, and how you would like it to look like on mobile...

Comment: On the desktop view there is a left pane and a right pane. The left pane has a list and the right pane has a dropdown. When switching to mobile view the expectation is to have both the dropdown and the list inline on top of the page. Since the dropdown is in a completely different container it is not possible to simply make them show up inline.

Comment: It sure as hell is. Give me a second

Comment: @Phiter is correct, use `@media` queries. Just google it and you'll see a lot of examples. You can easily hide/show selected elements according to the window size/resolution.

Answer (score -1):

You can detect if your site is in a mobile, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3540295/6859727) can help you.
Then, with Javascript you have to change the element parent, like in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7555459/6859727).

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Is there any way in which CSS can be used to accomplish this?

Comment: For example, with CSS3 you can change the styles if the screen size is < 800px, here's is my example: 
//On screen resize
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .gt-global-container {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
But you can't move the element to another parent.

Answer (score -1):

The only solution to your problem is to duplicate dropdown2 within container1 and hide it with media query on desktop viewport. Then show it only on smaller devices and hide the container2.